# get YouTube subscribers country and city via api

Tags: youtube-data-api

How can i get the information of YouTube subscribers like their demographics and their location in YouTube API V3 in data API or Analytics api.

Currently using the api node **youtube.subscriptions.list** we can get the subscribers list but only who have set their subscriptions visibility to public and we are getting only title, description and channelId. Is there any way by which we can get extra information of that subscriber

Comment: No, it is not possible. It is against the privacy law.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't available for individual subscribers or views, but it is available in aggregate: https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/dimensions

Comment: First read the document then answer. he is asking about the information about the subscribers not about the viewers and in aggregate you will get the information about the viewers not the subscribers. You can't get the more info about subscribers because it is against the privacy law.